# Native Element is not defined ionic after using ion-segment to show chart

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, chart.js

I am new to ionic so basically i want to display chart based on the segments buttons. However after i separated the charts,  there is an error native element is not defined in both createchart and createchart2 function (ts). "Cannot read property of Native element of undefined" Why is that so?

```
   <ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
      <ion-buttons start>

      </ion-buttons>
      <ion-title>
        Statistics
      </ion-title>
      <ion-buttons end>
        <button ion-button icon-only>
          <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content padding id="page3">



      <ion-card>
        <ion-card-header>
          <p (click)="openModal()">Number of courier based on location</p>

        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>
              <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="chartType1" color="warning">
                      <ion-segment-button value="chart1" >
                    Total Couriers based on Location
                      </ion-segment-button>
                      <ion-segment-button value="chart2">
                  Average Expense based on Location
                      </ion-segment-button>
                      <ion-segment-button value="chart3">
                  Number of Completed Deliveries in all Location
                      </ion-segment-button>
                      <ion-segment-button value="chart4">
                   Testing
                      </ion-segment-button>
                    </ion-segment>

                    <div [ngSwitch]="chartType1">
                          <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'chart1'">
                            <ion-item >
                              <div>
                                      <canvas chart-type="selectedType" #valueBarsCanvas></canvas>

                              </div>
                            </ion-item>
                          </ion-list>

                          <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'chart2'">
                                  <ion-item >
                                    <div>

                                          <canvas chart-type="selectedType" #lineCanvas></canvas>
                                    </div>
                                  </ion-item>
                                </ion-list>

                                <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'chart3'">
                                      <ion-item >
                                        <div>


                                        </div>
                                      </ion-item>
                                    </ion-list>

                                    <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'chart4'">
                                          <ion-item >
                                            <div>


                                            </div>
                                          </ion-item>
                                        </ion-list>

                        </div>


            <div class="col-md-10"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md" (click)="toggleChart()">Toggle Chart </button></div>



          <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="location" color="warning">
            <ion-segment-button value="north">
            North
            </ion-segment-button>
            <ion-segment-button value="east">
        East
            </ion-segment-button>
            <ion-segment-button value="south">
          South
            </ion-segment-button>
            <ion-segment-button value="west">
             West
            </ion-segment-button>
          </ion-segment>


        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>





  </ion-content>
```

My Typescript Code

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ToastController, ModalOptions, Modal, 
 ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import { Observable, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { StaffinfoProvider } from '../../providers/staffinfo-firebase';
import { staffInformation } from '../../models/staffInformation';
import { TaskFbProvider } from '../../providers/taskList-firebase';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-locationstat',
  templateUrl: 'locationstat.html'
})
export class LocationStatsPage {

  typecharts: any[];
  checkingData: any;
  checkingData2: any;
  regions: number[];
  ratingNorth = 0;
  ratingSouth = 0;
  ratingEast = 0;
  ratingWest = 0;
  staffInformation: staffInformation[];
  staffInformationN: staffInformation[]=[];
  staffInformationE: staffInformation[];
  staffInformationW: staffInformation[];
  staffInformationS: staffInformation[];
  status: number[];
  staffWExpense: any[];
  data: Observable<any[]>;
  ref: AngularFireList<any>;
  changeGraphX : any[];
  teams = [
    { value: 0, name: 'North' },
    { value: 1, name: 'East' },
    { value: 2, name: 'South' },
    { value: 3, name: 'West' },

  ];


  team = {
    value: 0,
    expense: false,
    month: 0
  }



  @ViewChild('valueBarsCanvas') valueBarsCanvas;
  @ViewChild('lineCanvas') lineCanvas;

  lineChart: any;
  doughnutChart: any;
  valueBarsChart: any;

  chartData = null;
  chartData2 = null;
  chartData3 = null;
  taskList2: any[];
  selectedcharts: any;
  selectedType: string;
  chartType = 'bar';
  chartType2 = 'line';
  mNExpense: number;
  mEExpense= 0;
  mSExpense= 0;
  mWExpense= 0;
  wNExpense= 0;
  wEExpense= 0;
  wSExpense= 0;
  wWExpense= 0;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private taskListService: TaskFbProvider, private modal: ModalController, private StaffinfoProvider: StaffinfoProvider) {
    this.typecharts = ['pie', 'bar']
    this.selectedType = "pie";
    this.changeGraphX = ['chart1', 'chart2'];
  }



  ngOnInit() {


    this.regions = [0, 0, 0, 0];

    this.StaffinfoProvider.getItemsByLoacation('North')

      .subscribe(staffInfosNorth => {

        this.staffInformationN = staffInfosNorth;

        this.regions[0] = staffInfosNorth.length;

        this.mNExpense = 0;
        this.wNExpense = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.staffInformationN.length; i++) {
          this.ratingNorth = this.ratingNorth + this.staffInformationN[i].rating;

          this.mNExpense = this.staffInformationN[i].monthlyEarnings + (this.mNExpense);

          this.wNExpense = this.staffInformationN[i].weeklyEarnings + this.wNExpense;        
        }

        this.ratingNorth = this.ratingNorth / this.staffInformationN.length;

        this.mNExpense = this.mNExpense / this.staffInformationN.length;

        this.wNExpense = this.wNExpense / this.staffInformationN.length;
      });

    this.StaffinfoProvider.getItemsByLoacation('East')

      .subscribe(staffInfosEast => {

        this.staffInformation = staffInfosEast;
        this.regions[1] = staffInfosEast.length;

        for (let i = 0; i < this.staffInformation.length; i++) {
          this.ratingEast = this.ratingEast + this.staffInformation[i].rating;
          this.mEExpense = this.staffInformation[i].monthlyEarnings + this.mEExpense;
          this.wEExpense = this.staffInformation[i].weeklyEarnings + this.wEExpense;
        }
        this.ratingEast = this.ratingEast / this.staffInformation.length;
        this.mEExpense = this.mEExpense / this.staffInformation.length;
        this.wEExpense = this.wEExpense / this.staffInformation.length;

      });

    this.StaffinfoProvider.getItemsByLoacation('South')

      .subscribe(staffInfosSouth => {

        this.staffInformation = staffInfosSouth;
        this.regions[2] = staffInfosSouth.length;

        for (let i = 0; i < this.staffInformation.length; i++) {
          this.ratingSouth = this.ratingSouth + this.staffInformation[i].rating;
          this.mSExpense = this.staffInformation[i].monthlyEarnings + this.mSExpense;
          this.wSExpense = this.staffInformation[i].weeklyEarnings + this.wSExpense;
        }
        this.ratingSouth = this.ratingSouth / this.staffInformation.length;
        this.mSExpense = this.mSExpense / this.staffInformation.length;
        this.wSExpense = this.wSExpense / this.staffInformation.length;

      });

    this.StaffinfoProvider.getItemsByLoacation('West')

      .subscribe(staffInfosWest => {

        this.staffInformation = staffInfosWest;
        this.regions[3] = staffInfosWest.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.staffInformation.length; i++) {
          this.ratingWest = this.ratingWest + this.staffInformation[i].rating;
          this.mWExpense = this.staffInformation[i].monthlyEarnings + this.mWExpense;
          this.wWExpense = this.staffInformation[i].weeklyEarnings + this.wWExpense;
        }
        this.ratingWest = this.ratingWest / this.staffInformation.length;
        this.mWExpense = this.mWExpense / this.staffInformation.length;
      this.wWExpense = this.wWExpense / this.staffInformation.length;

      });

  }


  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.StaffinfoProvider.returngraph1().

      valueChanges().subscribe(result => {
        this.checkingData = result;
        if (this.chartData) {
          this.updateCharts1(result);
        } else {
          this.createCharts(result);
        }

      });

      this.StaffinfoProvider.returngraph1().

      valueChanges().subscribe(result => {
        this.checkingData2 = result;
        if (this.chartData2) {
          this.updateCharts2(result);
        } else {
          this.createCharts2(result,result);
        }

      });



  }

  getChart1(context, chartType, data, options?) {
    return new Chart(context, {
      type: chartType,
      data: data,
      options: options
    });
  }


  createCharts2(data,data1) {
    this.chartData2 = data;
    this.chartData3 = data1;
    // Calculate Values for the Chart
    let chartData2 = this.getMonthlyNorthValues2();
    let chartData3 = this.getWeeklyNorthValues2();
    // Create the chart
    this.lineChart = new Chart(this.lineCanvas.nativeElement, {
      type: this.chartType2,
      data: {
        labels: Object.keys(this.teams).map(a => this.teams[a].name),
        datasets: [{
          data: chartData2,
          fill: false,
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',

          ],
          borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',

          ],
          borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
          data:chartData3,
          fill:false,
             backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 19, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 122, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',

          ],
          borderColor: [

            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 106, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 132, 192, 1)',

          ],

        }



      ]

      },
      options: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
            label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
              return '$'+data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItems.index] ;
            }
          }
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true

            }
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              callback: function (value, index, values) {
                return '$'+value ;
              },
              suggestedMin: 0,
              scaleStartValue: 0,
              scaleStepWidth: 0.1
            }
          }]
        },
      }
    });
  }




  getReportValues() {
    let reportByTeam = {
      0: this.regions[0],
      1: this.regions[1],
      2: this.regions[2],
      3: this.regions[3],
    }




    return Object.keys(reportByTeam).map(a => reportByTeam[a]);
  }


  getMonthlyNorthValues2() {
    let reportByTeam = {
      0: this.mNExpense,
      1: this.mEExpense,
      2: this.mSExpense,
      3: this.mWExpense,
    }




    return Object.keys(reportByTeam).map(a => reportByTeam[a]);
  }

  getWeeklyNorthValues2() {
    let reportByTeam = {
      0: this.wNExpense,
      1: this.wEExpense,
      2: this.wSExpense,
      3: this.wWExpense,
    }




    return Object.keys(reportByTeam).map(a => reportByTeam[a]);
  }



  createCharts(data) {
    this.chartData = data;

    // Calculate Values for the Chart
    let chartData = this.getReportValues();

    // Create the chart
    this.valueBarsChart = new Chart(this.valueBarsCanvas.nativeElement, {
      type: this.chartType,
      data: {
        labels: Object.keys(this.teams).map(a => this.teams[a].name),
        datasets: [{
          data: chartData,
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',

          ],
          borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',

          ],
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      },
      options: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
            label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
              return data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItems.index] + ' Courier';
            }
          }
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true

            }
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              callback: function (value, index, values) {
                return value + 'Couriers';
              },
              suggestedMin: 0,
              scaleStartValue: 0,
              scaleStepWidth: 0.1
            }
          }]
        },
      }
    });
  }



changeSelect(item){
this.changeGraphX = item;

if (item==this.changeGraphX[1]){
  this.valueBarsChart.destroy();

  this.createCharts2(this.checkingData2,this.checkingData2);
}
else {
    this.lineChart
}
}

chart1type(){
  this.lineChart.destroy();

  this.createCharts(this.checkingData);
}

chart2type(){
  this.valueBarsChart.destroy();

  this.createCharts2(this.checkingData2,this.checkingData2);
}

  toggleChart() {
    //destroy chart:
    this.valueBarsChart.destroy();
    //change chart type: 
    this.chartType = (this.chartType == 'bar') ? 'doughnut' : 'bar';
    //restart chart:
    this.createCharts(this.checkingData);

  }


changeChart(){

}


  updateCharts1(data) {
    this.chartData = data;
    let chartData = this.getReportValues();

    // Update our dataset
    this.valueBarsChart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
      dataset.data = chartData
    });
    this.valueBarsChart.update();
  }
  updateCharts2(data) {
    this.chartData2 = data;
    this.chartData3 = data;
    let chartData2 = this.getMonthlyNorthValues2();
    let chartData3 = this.getWeeklyNorthValues2();
    // Update our dataset
    this.lineChart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
      dataset.data = chartData2
      dataset.data = chartData3
    });
    this.lineChart.update();
  }
```

Comment: I have added the function chart1type() and chart2type() to the first and second ion-segment button but the error remains the same.